# image is to be aligned in right of a long text

Tags: android

I have a long single text and image, and I have to align image to the left of text in a way like text is wrapping the image means when image height finished then text should start from left like there is no image problem is that blank space of image width is left through out the screen in the left side. how to break text to write it from left after image height finish.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to understand the problem based on your description, maybe you should provide a sketch of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: please provide somecode to understand ur's situvation

Comment: @Egor i want to wrap image with text but image would be in left and text will start from right of image when image height finish then text will start from left like there is no image, problem is i have only single text how to break that text when image height finish.